# Are there any GUI's for Linux that doesn't use X11?

Tags: linux, security, x11

Are there any GUI's for Linux that doesn't use X11?

Since X has very poor security :O

e.g.: Ubuntu, Fedora - what else are there?

Goal: having a Desktop Environment without X. - what are the solutions? (e.g.: watch Flash with Google Chrome, Edit docs with LibreOffice, etc., not using text-based webbrowsers)

Maybe with framebuffers? But how? :O

Comment: Could you clarify what it is your are wanting to know: alternatives to X, or applications that can run without X? Ubuntu and Fedora are distros that can run with or without X...

Comment: sry, i updated the q

Comment: Saying that something “has bad security” is meaningless. Security is not an absolute qualification. Something isn't secure or insecure per se, but it can be more or less secure with respect to a given threat model.

Comment: @Gilles It could mean that X does not provide GUI Isolation and hence keylogging (passive attack) is a thread. Even installing one malicous X application can basically be a thread in this sence Lance is maybe referring to that this is not the "ideal security".

Comment: @humanityAndPeace - but OP might mean something completely different - like the regurgitated crap about magic cookies or perhaps even from before there was any authentication in X.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

*Note: apart from this paragraph, this answer was last updated in 2016. Since then, [Wayland](http://wayland.freedesktop.org/) has become a viable alternative to X11, although it's still mostly used as a backend for X11.*

No. X is the only usable GUI on Linux.

There have been competing projects in the past, but none that gained any traction. Writing something like X is hard, and it takes a lot of extra work to get something usable in practice: you need hardware drivers, and you need applications. Since existing applications speak X11, you need either a translation layer (so… have you written something new, or just a new X server?) or to write new applications from scratch.

There is one ongoing project that aims to supplant X: [Mir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mir_(software)). It's backed by Canonical, who want to standardize on it for [Ubuntu](https://unity.ubuntu.com/mir/) — but it hasn't gained a lot of traction outside Ubuntu, so it may not succeed more than [Wayland](http://wayland.freedesktop.org/) (which was designed for 3D performance, not for security) did. Mir does [aim](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Mir/Spec#Security) to improve on the X security model by allowing applications limited privileges (e.g. applications have to have some kind of privilege to mess with other applications' input and output); whether that scales when people want to take screenshots and define input methods remains to be seen.

You can run a few graphical applications on Linux without X with [SVGAlib](http://www.svgalib.org/). However that doesn't bring any extra security either (in addition to numerous other problems, such as poor hardware support, poor usability, and small number of applications). SVGAlib has had known security holes, and it doesn't get much attention, so it probably has many more. X implementations get a lot more attention, so you can at least mostly expect that the implementation matches the security model.

X has a very easily understood security model: any application that's connected to the X server can do anything. (That's a safe approximation, but a fairly realistic one.) You can build a more secure system on top of this, simply by isolating untrusted applications: put them in their own virtual environment, displaying on their own X server, and show that X server's display in a window. You'll lose functionality from these applications, for example you have to run things like window managers and clipboard managers in the host environment. There's at least one usable project based on this approach: [Qubes](http://qubes-os.org/Home.html).

Comment: What about the [directFB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DirectFB) project?

Comment: @humanityANDpeace DirectFB is a way for one application to access a video display. It's similar to SVGAlib, but with respect to security at least it's now maintained. It's not a GUI in the sense of a way to at least run multiple applications and switch between them, let alone do things like display multiple windows, copy-paste, etc.

Comment: What about [Skia](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5007242/199360) any chance to use it outside of Android? (like for example for making GUIs running on limited devices like the Rasperry Pi Zero.

Comment: @adib I don't think so. Android's graphic stack isn't cheap compared with X anyway.

Comment: This answer is from 2011. Are there any updates?

Comment: @becko Mir has made some progress. It's still very far from being a replacement for X — most applications that run on Mir use X11 on top of MIr.

Comment: MGR is a GUI for Unix (and Linux) that doesn't use X11. But it predates the web, and I doubt any functional web browser (let alone modern video player) supports it. In late 1980s it was released to one of the comp.sources.* newsgroups. I tried it once, but it was limited to monochrome.

Comment: It's been about 5 years since the last ping - any updates yet?

Comment: @MANA624 Yes: now Wayland has actually succeeded (whereas I think Mir is dead).

Answer (score 10):

The applications that you mention (Chrome, Flash, LibreOffice) are all built to run in X11 or a similar display server like [Wayland](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wayland_%28display_server_protocol%29).

It is possible to run all manner of applications[1] in the console, for example:

- email ([mutt](http://www.mutt.org/))
- web browsing ([w3m](http://w3m.sourceforge.net/))
- music ([mpd](http://mpd.wikia.com/wiki/Music_Player_Daemon_Wiki)/[ncmpcpp](http://unkart.ovh.org/ncmpcpp/))
- file managers ([vifm](http://vifm.sourceforge.net/))
- movies ([mplayer](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/)), etc.

In combination with a terminal multiplexer, like [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/), you can manage the various 'windows' that the applications run in.

All of these applications are available in the repositories of most distributions.

[1] For each example I have provided, there are probably at least two to three more applications in each category that will do much the same thing... You will need a [framebuffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_framebuffer) to make this work well.

Comment: Also `slrn`. Debian's `aptitude` also uses curses.

Answer (score 7):

[DirectFB](http://directfb.org/) is used in quite a lot in embedded applications. It provides a local-only windows and graphics environment with hardware acceleration etc. You can run X11 applications under it using [XDirectFB](http://www.directfb.org/index.php?path=Projects/XDirectFB)

Comment: What about the security aspect of the question? Can you tell if directFB is better security wise? i.e. that one graphical application cannot capture (keylog) the input of other applicatoins?

Answer (score 4):

There is [ncurses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses), known from midnight commander, yast and other command line tools. If you meant *real* graphics there is *Freedesktop.org*'s [Wayland](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wayland_(display_server_protocol)) or Canonical's *Mir*, both initiatives to replace X.
IFAIK there are possibilities to show videos on console/tty but a don't remember a name.

Comment: Unity isn't replacing X, it's replacing part of Gnome. You must be confusing it with Wayland.

Comment: @Gilles: indeed, I mixed that up and meant Wayland

Comment: @Gilles: Actually, Wayland is a *Gnome* initiative. The Canonical initiative to replace X is *Mir*

Comment: @MestreLion In 2011, Wayland was backed by Canonical. Indeed now they've switched to Mir.

Comment: @Gilles: Ok, thanks. Another self-correction: Wayland is a not a gnome project, it is a *freedsktop.org* project

Answer (score -1):

Guichan? http://guichan.sourceforge.net/oldsite/about.shtml . There's probably a ton more GUIs like guichan out there that don't require X, like picogui etc...